# Matplotlib axvspan - solid fill?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graphics

I'm using this line of code to create a vertical span across a graph using matplotlib.

```
matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan(datetime.datetime.strptime("09-10-2015", '%d-%m-%Y'), datetime.datetime.strptime(now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), '%d-%m-%Y'), fill=True, linewidth=0, color='r')
```

However I'd like it to go over the graph to hide the line on the graph. At the moment it just does this.

[image]

How can I make the fill of this axvspan solid and non transparent?

Answer (score 6):

It's not about transparency (which you can change with the `alpha` parameter). It's about `zorder` (a kind of distance to the user, lower zorder will be farther). You need to put the zorder of the `grid` below the zorder of the `axvspan` (which in turn should be below, I think, of the `plot`). Check the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(-1, 2, .01)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)

plt.plot(t, s,zorder=4)

p = plt.axvspan(1.25, 1.55, facecolor='g', alpha=1,zorder=3)

plt.axis([-1, 2, -1, 2])
plt.grid(zorder=2)

plt.show()
```

, which results in:

[image: Zorder of elements in matplotlib plot]