# How to remove contour/ path inside ploygon on basemap using matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am working with some weather data to plot contour lines on basemap using matplotlib. The data I have used (x, y and data) is uploaded here http://www.mediafire.com/download/0epjjdm8auit611/mslp.txt
here http://www.mediafire.com/download/1dn6p8nw96h2mmd/xlong.txt
and here http://www.mediafire.com/download/31suzsz6j7u2bgz/xlat.txt.
  The working example code is below:-

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=7, urcrnrlat=40,
            llcrnrlon=68, urcrnrlon=110, resolution='l')

x = np.loadtxt('xlong.txt', delimiter=',')
y = np.loadtxt('xlat.txt', delimiter=',')
Z = np.loadtxt('mslp.txt', delimiter=',')

x, y = m(x, y)
CS = plt.contour(x, y, Z, colors='b')

plt.show()
```

The above code gives me the following plot...

[image]

The plot is absolutely OK. But I would like to hide/ remove contour lines over a particular area. So, I have drawn a polygon over a basemap and tried to hide data beneath the polygon. The code I have used for doing is as follows:-

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon


def draw_screen_poly(lats, lons, m):
    x, y = m(lons, lats)
    xy = zip(x, y)
    poly = Polygon(xy, facecolor='red')
    plt.gca().add_patch(poly)

lats = [30, 35, 35, 30]
lons = [80, 80, 90, 90]

m = Basemap(projection='merc', llcrnrlat=7, urcrnrlat=40,
            llcrnrlon=68, urcrnrlon=110, resolution='l')

x = np.loadtxt('xlong.txt', delimiter=',')
y = np.loadtxt('xlat.txt', delimiter=',')
Z = np.loadtxt('mslp.txt', delimiter=',')

x, y = m(x, y)
CS = plt.contour(x, y, Z, colors='b')

draw_screen_poly(lats, lons, m)

plt.show()
```

The resulting image is lloking like below. As you can see, there is no effect of `facecolour` as it does not hide any data beneath it.

[image]

What I want to do is either remove contour lines passing through this polygon or hide/ clip the polygon area using image processing technique.

The solution I think of are:-

**1.  Apply some white colour to polygon region so that it matches the basemap colour and data is hidden (this is already done in the above example and does not work).**

**2.  Go through each contour from contour collection and check if it is passing through the polygon region. Finally remove it from plot.**

**3.  Finally, Chip off the polygon area.**

My mind is not proceeding beyond above ideas. Any solution to solve this issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Basemap toolkit for matplotlib follows most of the same logic as matplotlib itself. You'll notice that you have [zorder](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.drawcoastlines) arguments to give to your plot calls. You just need to make sure that the [zorder](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html) of the rectangle is higher than the `zorder` of the contour.

Recently I've given an awnser for a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423221/matplotlib-axvspan-solid-fill). The code logic should be reproducible for you example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(-1, 2, .01)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)

plt.plot(t, s,zorder=4)

p = plt.axvspan(1.25, 1.55, facecolor='g', alpha=1,zorder=3)

plt.axis([-1, 2, -1, 2])
plt.grid(zorder=2)

plt.show()
```

, notice how the `axvspan` and the `plot` data itself is forced to be on top of the `grid` (by tinkering with the `zorder`).

**EDIT:** Working example of contour plot with lower zorder than a rectangle.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)


# Create a simple contour plot with labels using default colors.  The
# inline argument to clabel will control whether the labels are draw
# over the line segments of the contour, removing the lines beneath
# the label
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z,zorder=3)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')

rect1 = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((0,0), 2, 1, color='yellow',zorder=5)

ax.add_patch(rect1)

plt.show()
```

, which results in:

[image: Rectangle overlapping countour plot]

, the original is:

[image: contour plot]

, which brings the labels there.

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. However, I have also have `clabel` for each contour lines. there is no effect on zorder on `clabel`. Any idea to remove this as well?

Comment: @sundar_ima It's probably a problem with something on your code sequence since I can't reproduce your problem. As you see in my edited post the labels are below the rectangle.

Comment: Thant worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Accepting your answer.